# MvvmCross and Xamarin.Forms - Android references don't include MvvmCross.Forms.Platforms.Android.Views

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, mvvmcross, .net-standard

I'm creating a simple MvvmCross proof of concept for Xamarin.Forms, an am checking against the sample project on GitHub.

My core project uses .Net Standard 2.0.

When I add MvvmCross.Forms to my Android project, I do not have

```
MvvmCross.Forms.Platforms.Android.Views
```

available as a namespace - the *Platforms* namespace isn't available.

Looking in the Android project file, I can see that the references to MvvmCross are as follows - i.e. referring to the .Net Standard libraries

```
    <Reference Include="MvvmCross">
  <HintPath>..\packages\MvvmCross.6.0.1\lib\netstandard2.0\MvvmCross.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="MvvmCross.Forms">
  <HintPath>..\packages\MvvmCross.Forms.6.0.1\lib\netstandard2.0\MvvmCross.Forms.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

Should the Android project be using the non .Net Standard libraries? If so how do I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

There's no problem using MVVMCross 6 with .Net Standard 2.0 and Xamarin Forms.

I'd suggest using the nuget packages in your Android project rather than referencing the DLLs.

Comment: That my point - the problem occurs  when I *do* use the NuGet packages in my Android project.

Answer (score 0):

I think the template for VS created the wrong type of project for my Android project. Adding a new Android project to the solution from scratch, and adding the appropriate NuGet packages, solved the problem and the references/namespaces were correctly added.